# What's a good news source for Computer Science?

Tags: soft-question, research-practice

If I want to be aware of the lastest discoveries in the Computer Science area, what's a good source of information? (preferable online)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ways for a mathematician to stay informed of current research in complexity theory](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/4090/ways-for-a-mathematician-to-stay-informed-of-current-research-in-complexity-theo).

Comment: This is terribly broad and out of scope as it stands. if limited to TCS, then the question above contains many of the answers indicated below. Voting to close.

Comment: @SureshVenkat you mean there really isn't a single source that informs about every relevant advance in Computer Science? That would be an answer, as well, and would made my question relevant and answerable.

Comment: @Kaveh no, I'm not focused in a single theory. But thanks for the advice.

Comment: I can't detect sarcasm on the internet, so I'm not sure if you're being sarcastic :). But no, there isn't a single source for all of computer science: the field is too broad

Comment: I don't understand what is the goal of this question. Since you have written "**every** advance occurred in Computer Science" and you are asking for a "single" resource, it seems to me you don't understand what is computer science and how large it is. I think the question should be closed as not a real question and the answers should be merged with the other question. Please also see the [FAQ].

Comment: I vote to close. But surprisingly not one other non-mod person thinks that way

Comment: -1 and virtually vote to close (I don't have enough rep.). The OP is almost asking for the meaning of life, can it be more broad than this? There is not even a single comment where the OP mentions the word 'theory'.

Comment: @SureshVenkat I was not being sarcastic. And I if there isn't a single source, I can accept you answer as correct if you post it. And I really thank you for answering.

Comment: @Kaveh if the area is too large, and there's no single source to be up to date with the advances of it, I can accept this as a correct answer if you post it. And thanks for answering.

Comment: This question is also useful for me to see if someone can be always up-to-date with all the news of this area. I was suspecting that it's too large, and no one could be aware of the whole thing, but I was not sure.

Comment: Have you checked [arXiv](http://arxiv.org/archive/cs)? If your question is "if someone can be always up-to-date with all the news of this area?" then I still think it is not suitable for cstheory. Please see the the [FAQ] to understand the scope of cstheory.

Answer (score 9):

[Theory of Computing Blog Aggregator](http://feedworld.net/toc/) for *theoretical* computer science

Comment: Does this talk about **every** advance occurred in Computer Science? Or this would be an ideal that I really can't find?

Comment: Keeping up with the bloggers, you will find every *major* advance in *theoretical* conference, such as faster matrix multiplication a few days ago and ACC0 != NEXP last year.  For the other subfields of computer science, I think this site is not appropriate to ask.

Comment: @Snowie: You may not realize it, but your statement is particularly controversial right now.  I think a safer statement would be that by following blogs one will get informed about results (new and old) that the blog owners think are important.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to follow a specific field, try [arxiv.org](http://arxiv.org/).

Comment: ...if researchers in that field post to ArXiv.

Comment: Also you can attend a relevant conference/workshop!

Answer (score 1):

I find the [arXiv](http://arxiv.org/) and the [TOC Blog Aggregator](http://feedworld.net/toc/) too much to follow.  If you just read [The Complexity Blog](http://blog.computationalcomplexity.org/), [Gödel's Lost Letter](http://rjlipton.wordpress.com/), and [Shtetl-Optimized](http://www.scottaaronson.com/blog/), you won't miss much theory news.

Comment: tsk tsk. you don't read the geomblog ? I'm shocked ! shocked ! ;)

Comment: If you rename it to Theoryblog and also inadvertently attract offended anonymous commenters arguing over matrix multiplication, I'll add it to this list. ;)

Comment: hmm. let me think up random controversial things to say :)

Comment: @Lev: I would agree with you if you had said, "theory news that is blogged at all."  I have not been able to find a blog I like for advances in distributed computing theory.  (Jared Saia's may be the closest, but he tends to talk about things that don't capture my attention.)  That doesn't mean that nothing is happening there -- arguably the developments are at least as important, from a theory-to-practice perspective, as the FOCS and STOC proceedings.  I think "theory news = what TCS bloggers blog about" upsets anonymous commenters. Not that their comments are appropriate.