# How do top researchers keep track new results in datastructures

Tags: soft-question, ds.data-structures, research-practice

Is there any twitter or some feed,which constantly sends new results which are being published to your mail.

Comment: This might be borderline off-topic, but not at a -3 level.

Comment: All of: ECCC mailing list, announcements of accepted conference papers to various email lists (e.g. TheoryNet, DMANET), word of mouth, Theory of Computing blog aggregator, checking key authors' websites, email alerts from the big commercial journal publishers.

Comment: I think this is essentially the same as [this one](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/4090/ways-for-a-mathematician-to-stay-informed-of-current-research-in-complexity-theo).

Comment: Voting to close as duplicate.

Comment: I am not sure if it is an exact duplicate, however I think it would make more sense to have one general question in place of one for each specific research topic. The conferences to follow will be different but we have [List of TCS conferences and workshops](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/7900/list-of-tcs-conferences-and-workshops) for them. Maybe it is better to make this one more general in place of closing it as a duplicate of the previous question.

Answer (score 5):

You can subscribe to the RSS of ArXiv, and you can keep track of which papers are getting accepted to the relevant conferences.

Comment: In particular, the cs.DS feed.

Answer (score 2):

You could get a Google Scholar profile, and it'll keep feeding you recommendations it thinks will be relevant to you, based on your publications.